# Opening AdWords in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-adwords

Recently (that is this year at least), I've had problems opening the AdWords site in Chrome; when I log in, the header displays and the main content area says `Loading...`. After a minute or so, that disappears and I'm left with a (largely) blank screen.

When I tried today, I copied the URL into IE9 - after a delay, it eventually loaded the mobile version of AdWords. So I tried in Opera - it says that AdWords is not viewable in Opera. So then I tried again in IE9, and finally I could access my campaigns through the usual interface.

I don't dip into AdWords that often, so I can't say when exactly this problem started occurring but I can say that I have been using Chrome for a long time, and I know that AdWords did used to work in the past.

I've done some searches, and there seems to be some hearsay evidence going way back to suggest that Chrome has had previous problems with AdWords but the sources aren't authoritative and both AdWords and Chrome have changed a lot over time.

Is this a common problem? And more importantly, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I will delete my answer as I was mistaken and thought this was for AdSense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found!

AdBlock Plus was enabled for this site—exempting the AdWords site, did the trick.